# SVG text disappears on larger label

Tags: css, graph, svg, charts, morris.js

I am using Morris.js for making charts. Morris.js uses SVG to draw the graphs. I have set up a JSbin here: [JSbin example](http://jsbin.com/OzAruwu/1/edit)

Morris.js uses Raphael to draw the svg graphs. The issue is with the labels on the X-Axis. They disappear when the size of labels is too large. I tinkered around with the size of the div element holding the graph and font size of the labels but since the labels are dynamically generated for various users I cannot decide on a fixed value. An ideal solution would be to have the text wrapped up. What can be done to counter the situation?
Morris.js uses the following snippet to make the `text` svg element.

```
 this.raphael.text(xPos, yPos, text).attr('font-size', '11').attr('font-family', 'calibri').attr('fill', this.options.gridTextColor);
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a solution, but you could always just do a nameofplace.substr(0,14) type solution applied to the dynamic variable.

Comment: Had a similar issue, turning texts in my svg to paths (using inkscape) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems raphael supports multiline strings by putting "\n" in the text. This could be a cheap solution for you, systematically replacing " " by "\n" in your labels.

The other (more tricky) solution would be to replace the "text" element in the SVG generated by raphael by a foreign element that allows word wrapping:

```
<foreignObject x="20" y="10" width="150" height="200">
   <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Wrapping text using some foreignObject in SVG!</p>
</foreignObject>
```

or if you need a fallback:

```
<switch>
  <foreignObject x="160" y="10" width="150" height="200"><p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Wrapping text using some foreignObject in SVG!</p></foreignObject>
  <text x="20" y="20">Your SVG viewer cannot display html.</text>
</switch>
```

I don't know the best way to do this replacement of "text" by a foreign object: either after the Morris rendering or by hacking Morris/Raphael.

Comment: Thank you for super trick! I have read SVG spec one year ago, but somehow missed this tag definition! Unfortunately, the Morris lib, calculate the width of label and makes decision to draw or not to draw the odd labels. Therefore, after rendering, we have no chance "to fix" it by replacing a part of html/svg tags. But anyway, <foreignObject /><p /> is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem definition need more clarification,

at my end the code you have sent works fine, also I have replicated the same in [`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/2DT4x/1/) that is also working fine..

I think the label problem is done automatically as I have tested the default size you have kept was carrying width 385px when looking in to CSS and 518px when looking the same, in both case the rendered labels were different, in-fact the label exceeding certain width were not rendered. SO there is no meaning to set style and override.

I think the things are built in library. So its a long way to go, or change the library.

let me know which will be convenient way, I will help you accordingly :)

Edit:
However, you can change property of GridTextSize: that is 16 by default

[`Fiddle2`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/2DT4x/2/) here I have updated

'gridTextSize:8' that displays all text in size 8.

Not perfect but will do :)

Comment: Changing font size would not work. The example you set has 'North America' and 'South America' missing on my screen. I think it would require a library change.

Comment: Yes Library change is required, but this works if the page width is more. This is an automatic calculation within library which works like `min width = Total width/no of Bar. If Test Size > min width ( do not render Text node)`

Answer (score 3):

Download not minimized morris.js from [there](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/). In zip-archive you can find a file *morris.js*. Open it in edit mode and change value of default label angle parameter (line 133):

```
133 |     xLabelAngle: 90,//original value 0
```

Now, if you really need it minimized, you can compress file by any online js compress tool.